# Could not find a declaration file for module '@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Getting the error as per the title. The solutions I found were for Typescript, and as I am very new to JS and Tailwind I couldn't make anything out of it. How do I solve this issue?

```js
    module.exports = {
      content: [],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
      ],
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the asset-ratio NPM package? https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

Comment: yes, I have and it's still complaining

Answer (score 11):

You need to install the aspect ratio module.

From your project's root directory, run this:

```
npm install --save-dev @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio
```

Make sure that you re-run your project after installing this before trying out the fix.

Comment: thanks, but I have already done so and it's still complaining

Comment: @J.Doe you sure you’ve called that in the root directory of your project?

Answer (score 2):

When I installed this plugin I got the same issue as above.
However, I followed the below steps to fix this:-

1. Close the dev server.
2. `npm install -D @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio`
3. Hit this command `npm i` again.
4. Start your server again.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio) you need to disable the core `aspectRatio` plugin to avoid conflicts with the native aspect-ratio utilities included in Tailwind CSS v3.0

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  corePlugins: {
    aspectRatio: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles across this issue:

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder in your root dir
2. Install all tailwind packages you need manually:

   - `npm i --force tailwindcss`
   - `npm i --force @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio`
   - ...
3. Run `npm i` to install all your other packages

This worked for me.

Otherwise have a look at this thread for more potential solutions (e.g., configuring your workspaces in package.json): https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

U dont hv to worry about this warning
tailwind config is a js file
but ur editor and linter will still try to warn u as ur main project is a typescript project
this warning in specific comes from there not begin any type declarations in that tailwind plugin package but the package exists and will still work anyway

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).